# dirty/pristine changes in react-native with redux-form result in keyboard being hidden and flicker

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux-form

I use *redux-form* with *react-native* and for some reason when the state of the form changes from `dirty` to `pristine`when user types the first char into an input the keyboards gets hidden and screen flickers. This happens on the Android Nexus 5X device.

View component:

```
const TextField = ({placeholder: p, ...props}) =>
    <Field {...props}
           component={({input}) => {
               return <TextInput
                   value={input.value}
                   onChange={input.onChange}
                   secureTextEntry={props.type === 'password'}
                   placeholder={p}
               />
           }}/>

const Login = ({submit}) =>
    <View>
        <Text>You need to log in</Text>
        <TextField placeholder="Name"
                   name="name"/>
        <Button title="Login" onPress={submit}/>
    </View>

export default login(Login)
```

`login` is HOC which is wrapped in

```
reduxForm({
            form: 'login',
            initialValues: {
                name: 'a',
            },
            onSubmit: vals => {
                console.log('submitting', vals)
            }
        })
```

What kind of event in *react-native* can create such behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the problem had nothing to do with *redux-form* but  with using an inline anonymous component

```
({input}) => {
               return <TextInput
                   value={input.value}
                   onChange={input.onChange}
                   secureTextEntry={props.type === 'password'}
                   placeholder={p}
               />
           }
```

This was done just for 'prototyping' purposes so it was overlooked.

Declaring component normally like `const TextFieldComponent = ({input}) => ...` solved the problem.

Comment: I get the error as well but unlike you I do not have any inline components in this case. Anyone who might know what the problem is?